# Is there a good way to get the result of multiple AJAX delete requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a selected `id` list:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

And there is a delete url for me to delete the selected items:

```
/api/users/<pk>/delete/
```

But the url can only pass one `id` each time.

So, there should use a for-loop to delete the selected items.

The delete method is below, the `delete_url(id)` is the url, the `(response) => {}` is success callback, the last is error callback:

```
this.$http.delete(delete_url(id), (response) => {

}, (error) => {

})
```

You know one time only can delete one item, but if I use a for-loop to execute the method, how can I know when all the delete request execute finish? And how can I know whether it delete all success?

Comment: Why dont you pass the id's as JSON.stringify data?
BTW, if you do for loop, you can check all the success results.

Comment: You can use promise along with async and await, which browser are you using?

Comment: Please don't forget to write exact framework or language for which you are asking question in tag because different javascript frameworks are use same function names in different way

Comment: You can use a for loop then have a counter in the callback. Once the counter equals the length of your array you know every request has finished.

Comment: consider changing the backend controller to handle the json of ids.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I use the Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @AlexanderLallier Tell me how, the `this.$http.delete()` method is async.

Comment: @244boy I have provided a new answer demonstrating what I was talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a for loop. The for loop sends all the requests immediately and then counts the number of times the request callback fires, once that number matches the length of the array you know all requests have completed.

```
var someArray = [1, 3, 5, 7],
    someArrayLength = someArray.length
    callbackCount = 0,
    i,

for (i = 0; i < someArrayLength; i++) {
  this.$http.delete(delete_url(someArray[i]), (response) => {
    callbackCount++;

    if (callbackCount === someArrayLength) {
      // All callbacks have been made you can continue on
    }
  }, (error) => {
    callbackCount++

    if (callbackCount === someArrayLength) {
      // All callbacks have been made you can continue on
    }
  })
}
```

*Note: Since the error case and normal case are segregated I had to add the if check twice*

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by writting a recursive function where in success callback you call your recursive function. for example

```
function deleteMany(index=0){
     if (index < deleteArray.length){
         var id = deleteArray[index]
         this.$http.delete(delete_url(id), (response) => {
             deleteMany(index+1)
         }, (error) => {
           //your error handling logic here

         })
     } 
}
```

Comment: but how about the request fail?

Comment: you can handle it in error callback, that is positioned behind success callback in delete method arguments, and you can there decide whether you want to continue iterating over your list or throw an error, notify the user ... dealers choice =)

Comment: I also don't think this is a good solution, at least this should be async.

Comment: there is also finally callback after error callback in argument list, if you do not care for the result of the call

Comment: i found this post that might help you 
https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/